# How to make a multi pane on highstock (highcharts) which contain a stacked area graph?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to know if it will be possible to use the two pane view (as [this example](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume)) with a stacked area graph ?

I tryed to make it works in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g2xDj/2/, but, the stacked area graph is not displayed.

```
     var stacked_data =  [{
                    name: 'Asia',
                    data: [[1364292000,502], [1364294000,635], [1364296000,809], [1364298000,947], [1364300000,1402], [1364302000,3634], [1364304000,5268]]
                }, {
                    name: 'Africa',
                    data: [[1364292000,106], [1364294000,107], [1364296000,111], [1364298000,133], [1364300000,221], [1364302000,767], [1364304000,1766]]
                }, {
                    name: 'Europe',
                    data: [[1364292000,163], [1364294000,203], [1364296000,276], [1364298000,408], [1364300000,547], [1364302000,729], [1364304000,628]]
                }];

               var line_data = [[1364292000,502], [1364294000,635], [1364296000,809], [1364298000,947], [1364300000,1402], [1364302000,3634], [1364304000,5268]];

            // create the chart
            $('#container').highcharts('StockChart',

   {
                chart : {
                    //type: 'area',
                    renderTo : 'container',
                    zoomType: 'x'
                }, 
                plotOptions: {
                     area: {
                         stacking: 'normal'
                     }
                 },
                rangeSelector: {
                    selected: 1
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'AAPL Historical'
                },

                yAxis: [{
                    title: {
                        text: 'Load'
                    },
                    height: 200,
                    lineWidth: 2
                },
                {
                   title: {
                        text: 'Load 2'
                   },
                   top: 300,
                   height: 100,
                   offset: 0,
                   lineWidth: 2    
                }
                ],
                series: [
                    { 
                      name: "area",
                      data: stacked_data,
                      yAxis: 0
                    },{
                      name: "line",
                      data: line_data,
                      yAxis: 1
                    }]
            });
        });
```

Anybody have an idea to help me ?

Comment: How to add a scroll with multi-panes? Please help on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54467415/highcharts-multi-panes-and-scrollbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you have incorrect structure of series, because in stackedArea you try to push "series" structure for data.

Additionaly you should multiply all timestamp by 1000 to achieve JS timestamp format.

Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/g2xDj/4/

```
  var series = [{
        name: 'Asia',
        data: [
            [1364292000000, 502],
            [1364294000000, 635],
            [1364296000000, 809],
            [1364298000000, 947],
            [1364300000000, 1402],
            [1364302000000, 3634],
            [1364304000000, 5268]
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'Africa',
        data: [
            [1364292000000, 106],
            [1364294000000, 107],
            [1364296000000, 111],
            [1364298000000, 133],
            [1364300000000, 221],
            [1364302000000, 767],
            [1364304000000, 1766]
        ]
    }, {
        name: 'Europe',
        data: [
            [1364292000000, 163],
            [1364294000000, 203],
            [1364296000000, 276],
            [1364298000000, 408],
            [1364300000000, 547],
            [1364302000000, 729],
            [1364304000000, 628]
        ]
    }];

    var line_data = {
        type:'line',
        yAxis:1,
        data:[
        [1364292000000, 502],
        [1364294000000, 635],
        [1364296000000, 809],
        [1364298000000, 947],
        [1364300000000, 1402],
        [1364302000000, 3634],
        [1364304000000, 5268]
                     ]};
```

series.push(line_data);