# Highcharts Multi-Panes and Scrollbar

Tags: highcharts

How to add a scroll with multi-panes?

Please look at the fiddle, 3rd pane is overlapping

```
yAxis: [{
    title: { text: 'Coffee Cups'},
    height: '60%',
    offset: 0,
    lineWidth: 2
  }, {
    title: { text: 'Hazelnut Cups' },
    top: '65%',
    height: '60%',
    offset: 0,
    lineWidth: 2
  }, {
    title: { text: 'Choco Cups' },
    top: '130%',
    height: '60%',
    offset: 0,
    lineWidth: 2
  }]
```

Note: In my scenario, it can be 100 multi panes.

[image]

Comment: Please look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n3tw9f46/. The last pane is overlapping and I can not scroll it further.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the heights of your y-axes is more than `100%` which causes the overlapping. You should not exceed 100%:

```
        yAxis: [{
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Coffee Cups'
            },
            height: '33.33%',
            offset: 0,
            lineWidth: 2
        }, {
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Hazelnut Cups'
            },
            top: '33.33%',
            height: '33.33%',
            offset: 0,
            lineWidth: 2
        }, {
            title: {
                text: 'Hazelnut Cups'
            },
            top: '66.66%',
            height: '33.33%',
            offset: 0,
            lineWidth: 2
        }]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g7uto6xc/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.height

**EDIT:**

After a lot of customizations, the wanted result was achieved:

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u293pvnj/

Comment: Thanks, @ppotaczek for a quick reply. As I mentioned, I can have 100 panes on y-axis and if I make the total height 100%, series are very small and overlaps.

Comment: Hi Shafaq Kazmi, Unfortunately the scrollbar in Highcharts is assigned to one axis and adding the ability to scroll through all panes would require a lot of customisation. You can try to overwrite `setUpScrolling` and `applyFixed` or you can add your idea on Highcharts user voice: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api

Comment: @Shafaq Kazmi, I have edited the answer, please check the live demo.